# Snap directory full, automatic python update broke all python code

Tags: python, snap, ubuntu-pro

I enabled app updates in Ubuntu Pro on a 20.04 LTS box but any attempt to run python code breaks immediately on import.

For example, entering

> import pandas as pd

in a python3.8 shell returns a message:

> numpy: cannot import name 'core' from partially initialized module 'numpy' (most likely due to a circular import)

followed by a reference to the __init__.py file.  Not really useful as this led me on a day long wild goose chase!

I compared the current python3.8 packages with those from the day before - there were many differences - so not realising what snap did, I just moved the site-packages directory aside and copied the old directory from the rsnapshot archive.  The same result occurred.

Clearing the cache and removing all the .pyc files similarly failed.

I've now disabled esm-apps from updating.  Many python packages specify compatibility version limits so I need to stop automatic updates for python.

Sleeping on it (always recommended), I checked the journal and saw a message

> Failed to set priority of timezone change event sources: No space left on device

at the update time and date.  df immediately revealed that this was the /snap/ "partition" with all /dev/loop* using 100%.  Bingo.

**And these are my questions:**

What is the best way to recover this broken system?
Is it to disable snap and revert to the old versions (which may break pro)?
Can I copy the snap "partition" somewhere?
How do I increase the limit from 2.5G (which is rather small)?
How do I prune the snap partition?
Is there way to prompt snap to complete the update?

parted:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD30PURZ-85A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:
Number Start    End   Size File system Name Flags
1     1049kB 2097kB 1049kB bios_grub
2     2097kB 526MB   524MB ext4
3      526MB 1064MB  538MB fat32 msftdata
4     1064MB 3001GB 3000GB ext4

Model: ATA KINGSTON SH103S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:
Number Start   End  Size    Type File system Flags
1     1049kB 120GB 120GB primary linux-swap(v1)

Model: Samsung SSD 960 PRO 512GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:
Number Start   End  Size File system Name Flags
1     1049kB 512GB 512GB raid

Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md0: 1024GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:
Number Start    End   Size File system Name Flags 
1     1049kB  717GB  717GB ext4 
2      717GB  967GB  250GB ext4 
3      967GB 1024GB 57.2GB linux-swap(v1) swap

Model: Samsung SSD 960 PRO 512GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:
Number Start   End  Size File system Name Flags
1     1049kB 512GB 512GB raid
```

df:

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev 63G 0 63G 0% /dev
tmpfs 13G 3.8M 13G 1% /run
/dev/md0p1 657G 201G 423G 33% /
tmpfs 63G 0 63G 0% /dev/shm
tmpfs 5.0M 4.0K 5.0M 1% /run/lock
tmpfs 63G 0 63G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md0p2 229G 16G 202G 8% /var
/dev/loop0 9.7M 9.7M 0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/246
/dev/loop1 56M 56M 0 100% /snap/core18/2667
/dev/loop2 9.9M 9.9M 0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/264
/dev/loop3 106M 106M 0 100% /snap/core/16574
/dev/loop5 64M 64M 0 100% /snap/core20/2182
/dev/loop4 106M 106M 0 100% /snap/core/16202
/dev/loop6 64M 64M 0 100% /snap/core20/2105
/dev/loop7 56M 56M 0 100% /snap/core18/2812
/dev/loop8 75M 75M 0 100% /snap/core22/1033
/dev/loop9 50M 50M 0 100% /snap/snapd/17950
/dev/loop10 41M 41M 0 100% /snap/snapd/20671
/dev/loop11 75M 75M 0 100% /snap/core22/1122
/dev/loop12 92M 92M 0 100% /snap/lxd/24061
tmpfs 13G 4.0K 13G 1% /run/user/1000
```

snap:

```
Name Version Rev Tracking Publisher Notes
canonical-livepatch 10.8.1 264 latest/stable canonical** -
core 16-2.61.1 16574 latest/stable canonical** core
core18 20231027 2812 latest/stable canonical** base
core20 20240111 2182 latest/stable canonical** base
core22 20240111 1122 latest/stable canonical** base
lxd 4.0.9-a29c6f1 24061 4.0/stable/… canonical** -
snapd 2.61.1 20671 latest/stable canonical** snapd
```

Comment: "*df immediately revealed that this was the /snap/ "partition" with all /dev/loop using 100%. Bingo.*" False positive: Snaps are squashfs read-only filesystems. When mounted, they always show as 100% in `df`. That's normal behavior for snaps.

Comment: So why does it mark in the journal that there is no more space on device?  The drive is 2*500GB NVMe mounted as RAID0 with partition 1 (/dev/md0p1) size 657GB only 33% used.

Comment: For "no space on device", please edit your question to show us your complete `sudo parted --list` output and your complete `df -h` output. For snap-related issues, also show us the complete output of `snap list`

Comment: Did you install numpy with snap?

Comment: @Archisman no like the whole stack it was installed using pip3, the dedicated python package manager.